# How to get value from cookie which http mode is true

Tags: javascript, http, cookies

I want to get cookie value which http mode is true using js.

```
var x = document.cookie;
```

Using that I only that value which http mode is false (example:Nopcommerce.RecentlyViewedProducts).

In this picture I want get value Nop.customer. How to get that?

[image: Details Picture Here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this. The whole point of the `HttpOnly` flag on a cookie is that it cannot be accessed by client-side scripts. It's just sent by the browser to the server. From [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly#What_is_HttpOnly.3F):

> If the HttpOnly flag (optional) is included in the HTTP response header, the cookie cannot be accessed through client side script (again if the browser supports this flag). As a result, even if a cross-site scripting (XSS) flaw exists, and a user accidentally accesses a link that exploits this flaw, the browser (primarily Internet Explorer) will not reveal the cookie to a third party.